# Selenium and Firefox on Ubuntu: focusing to the new tab

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am working on Selenium and Firefox in Ubuntu14.04. I created a new tab by send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't'), but keep giving commands on the first tab, maybe because I didn't focus on the new tab correctly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver =  webdriver.Firefox()
main_window = driver.current_window_handle

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
driver.get("http://www.bing.com")

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
driver.get("https://github.com/login")
```

There is no error while running this code.

I make a new tab after go to google.com, and the screen changes to a blank page on the new tab. After that, I wrote driver.switch_to_window(main_window) to focus on the new tab to make sure next lines of code will happen on the new tab. But as driver.get("http://www.bing.com") is executed, screen goes back to the first tab where google.com is present, and changes google.com to bing.com. Same thing for the next code. Another new tab created, but goes back to first tab as driver.get("https://github.com/login") executed and bing.com becomes github.com/login.

I thought I focused on the current visible tab by

main_window = driver.current_window_handle; driver.switch_to_window(main_window),

But this didn't work well.
How can I load all 3 webpages on 3 different tabs?

SPECIFICATIONS:

- Selenium 3.0.2
- firefox 45.0.1
- Ubuntu 14.04 amd 64bit
- python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

Please try following solution and let me know if it's not what you're actually looking for:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
google_window = driver.current_window_handle # Define main window

driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.bing.com')") # Open Bing window
bing_window = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != google_window][0] # Define Bing window

driver.execute_script("window.open('https://github.com/login')") # Open GitHub window
github_window = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window not in [google_window, bing_window]][0] # Define GitHub window
```

After all 3 windows opened you can simply navigate as:

```
driver.switch_to_window(bing_window)
...# do something
driver.switch_to_window(google_window)
...# do something
driver.switch_to_window(github_window)
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I wanted to create tabs and put focus on the new tab. Your answer is about making new Window of Firefox and switch between them.

Comment: What do you mean `"put focus on the new tab"`? And what for? "Switching" to new tab means "focusing" on it... right?

Comment: Not exactly. in Selenium, even if switching to a new tab is done, you may not be able to do anything if focusing on the new tab is made. switching and  focusing are different, as far as I know. See the code at https://gist.github.com/lrhache/7686903  .  there is a comment saying # Put focus on current window which will, in fact, put focus on the current visible tab
->browser.switch_to_window(main_window)

Comment: Soooo?... `browser.switch_to_window(main_window)`!  **switch_to_window**! **switch**! :) This is **focusing on new window**! This is exactly what my code do: you opens `URL` in new tab, switch to it, handle everything on that page... What's the problem? I don't get it :)